# How do I know which pod a container is running in?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, k3d

Sorry about a newbie question. I am trying to deploy an image into k3d (a dockerized version of k3s).

```
k3d image import -c my-cluster registry.gitlab.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/hello123
```

Now I can see the image on a node:

```
kubectl get node my-node -o json | grep hello123
```

However, the documentation doesn't say much about what "import" does. Is my image running? Is it allocated to a pod yet? Where can I find its logs?

If I knew what pod it's running in, I could do `kubectl logs`. The list of the cluster's pods doesn't show anything relevant.

I am beginning to think my image isn't running yet.

Edit: This if further confirmed by

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}" |\
tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |\
sort |\
uniq -c
```

showing nothing relevant.

What's the next step?

Comment: From the naming, I'd think it just imports the image into the "cluster" so that it doesn't have to be pulled again to create a pod. I don't think it does anything more than that. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have just pulled the image to the cluster registry, the image has not been yet assigned to a pod.

Once you create a pod with the same image and image tag, it will try to pull from the local registry.

If you could ssh to the k8s node (`kubectl get nodes -o wide` and `ssh user@nodeip`), you can run the docker commands like:

```
docker images
```

You can expect to see the image that you pulled in the list.

If non of the pods are running the `docker ps` will return you an empty list.

Comment: Wow, that's the question I was going to ask next, thanks! How do I find user? My node only has an internal ip, I guess I'll need to give it an external one, how?

Comment: you will have to connect with your admin to know what username and password are being used while creating these nodes, if you are creating the k3d cluster on your own, please google to know what are the default username and password.

Comment: I am the admin, this is a local installation. I think it's found in `~/.kube/config` under `contexts.context.user`. However, it times out, probably because the node needs a public IP?

Comment: no, the node does not need a public IP, if you are within the network, you should be able to ssh using internal IP

Comment: I don't think I am. "By default, k3d creates a new (docker) network for every new cluster."